# Remove consecutive whitespaces and all newlines in String

Tags: swift, regex

I have a screen in which I show message previews of users. The previews should not contain newlines and consecutive whitespaces, exactly like the message previews in WhatsApp.

I currently have this code:

```
// String extension
public func prepareForInOverviewOrPushNotification() -> String {
    replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: " ")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: " {2,}", with: " ", options: .regularExpression)
}
```

This works, but I am calling this code in a hot loop and I want to improve the performance. The `.regularExpression` isn't cached and 2 `replace`s take place. I looked into the compiled `Regex` and `NSRegularExpression`, but with `Regex` I don't see a 'replace' option and with `NSRegularExpression` I need to convert my `String` to an `NSString` which doesn't help performance either.

This is a test which should remain working:

```
import MyProject
import XCTest

class StringOverviewTest: XCTestCase {
    func test() {
        check(input: "hi", expected: "hi")
        // Double whitespace
        check(input: "hi  X", expected: "hi X")
        check(input: """
                     hi 


                     weird long text

                     1
                     """, expected: "hi weird long text 1")
    }

    func check(
        input: String,
        expected: String
    ) {
        XCTAssertEqual(input.prepareForInOverviewOrPushNotification(), expected)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[ \n]+` (one or more spaces or newlines) instead of replacing newlines with space and then shrinking two or more spaces with a single space:

```swift
public func prepareForInOverviewOrPushNotification() -> String {
    replacingOccurrences(of: "[\n ]+", with: " ")
}
```

Or, just use `\s+`:

```swift
public func prepareForInOverviewOrPushNotification() -> String {
    replacingOccurrences(of: #"\s+"#, with: " ")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I went for the `[\n ]+` way. Is there any difference between that and `\s+`?

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, in ICU regex flavor, `\s` matches any Unicode whitespace chars, including non-breaking hyphens, line separator symbols, etc.